# How save terminal output when feeding it with named pipe

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, named-pipe

We know that we can save the result of a program in Linux terminal with below syntax:

```
terminal.out > result.txt
```

or

```
terminal.out | tee result.txt
```

But I can't save the output of the program when I am feeding it with a named pipe, like below:

```
terminal.out < pipe_in | tee result.txt
```

or

```
terminal.out < pipe_in > result.txt
```

could anyone please tell me what the correct syntax is?

Comment: The syntax is correct in many shells. If it doesn't work for you then most likely there is something unusual with `terminal.out`. It may not read from its stdin at all (e.g. it waits for input from `/dev/tty` while you're waiting for it to read `pipe_in`); or it may accumulate data and delay processing until the other end of the pipe is closed (this is normal if it needs to know all the input before it does anything); or something else. What is `terminal.out`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `terminal.out < pipe_in | tee result.txt` syntax is correct; here's an example in action:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ mkfifo foo
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ cat - < foo | tee bar
```

In another shell--

```
echo "Hello, world!" > foo
```

Then we see the output in the original terminal:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ cat - < foo | tee bar
Hello, world!
```

And the saved output in `./bar`:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ cat bar
Hello, world!
```

Here, `cat -` is reading from `stdin`, the `stdout` is piped to `tee`, the output is displayed on the terminal and is also saved to `./bar`.

You could also use `cat` to send the output from the named pipe to your program, e.g. `cat pipe_in | terminal.out | tee result.txt`.